# Tornado asynchttpclient results in None

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, tornado

I've been stuck with this for quite a few hours. I'm trying to use the `AsyncHTTPClient` to fetch the home page of a website say Google. A function to do so is defined within the same class, code as follows:

```
client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

@asynchronous
def getUrlRes(self,url,params,req_type):
    req1 = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url="http://www.google.com", method="GET")
    self.client.fetch(req1,self.urlCallBack)
    self.finish()

def urlCallBack(self, response):
    print response
```

What am I doing wrong?

An alternate approach to follow, which again didn't work for me, but works for all:

```
@asynchronous
@gen.engine
def getUrlRes(self,url,params,req_type):
    req1 = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url="http://www.google.com", method="GET")
    response = yield gen.Task(self.client.fetch,req1)
    self.finish()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this

```
import urllib2

@tornado.web.asynchronous
def getUrlRes(self, url, params, req_type):
    def urlCallBack(response):
        print "Got response {}".format(response)
        self.finish()
    self.client.fetch("http://www.google.com?" + urllib2.urlencode(params), 
                      urlCallBack, method=req_type)
```

The key here is that you need to call `self.finish` inside the callback. Calling `finish` too soon will not give the request time to complete.

if you want the caller of `getUrlRes` to have access to the completed `response`, you can pass it another callback function, then call it once the request has completed:

```
def caller(self):
    def _callback(response):
        print "Doing something cool"
    getUrlRes("google.com", params, "GET", callback=_callback)

@tornado.web.asynchronous
def getUrlRes(self, url, params, req_type, callback=None):
    def urlCallBack(response):
        print "Got response {}".format(response)
        if callback:
            _callback(response)  # call the passed callback here
        self.finish()
    self.client.fetch("{}?{}".format(url, urllib2.urlencode(params)), 
                      urlCallBack, method=req_type)
```

Comment: how can I make this function return something? if I do return response.body in urlCallBack function, I see the runtime takes long but does'nt result in anything

Comment: If you wanted the caller of `getUrlRes` to have access to `response`, you could pass an argument to `getUrlRes` that is a function that takes the response as an argument. You could then call this function inside `urlCallBack`. This type of programming leads to "callback soup", which gets confusing. You could also program it as an inline callback (like you have above with `gen.Task`), which would have the same effect but simplify the code and increase readability.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call a `gen.engine` function and get a return value from it, there's a few rules:

1. The caller and callee must both be decorated with `gen.engine`. Note that `getUrlRes` doesn't need to be decorated with `asynchronous`, however: only a `get` or `post` method needs that decorator.
2. The callee needs to take a `callback` argument.
3. The actual call is done with `yield gen.Task`.
4. The callee returns a value by passing the value to the callback.

Putting it all together, here's a RequestHandler that fetches google.com and displays the contents:

```
class Main(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        response = yield gen.Task(self.getUrlRes,
                                  "http://www.google.com", [], "GET")

        print 'got response of length', len(response.body)
        self.finish(response.body)

    @gen.engine
    def getUrlRes(self, url, params, req_type, callback):
        req1 = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url, method=req_type)
        response = yield gen.Task(self.client.fetch, req1)
        callback(response)
```

You can read more about `gen.engine` and subroutines in my article, [Refactoring Tornado Code With gen.engine](http://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-code-with-gen-engine/).

By the way, Tornado 3 has made this all much easier with the new `gen.coroutine` decorator:

```
class Main(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        response = yield self.getUrlRes("http://www.google.com", [], "GET")
        print 'got response of length', len(response.body)
        self.finish(response.body)

    @gen.coroutine
    def getUrlRes(self, url, params, req_type):
        req1 = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url, method=req_type)
        response = yield self.client.fetch(req1)
        raise gen.Return(response)
```

`@asynchronous`, `gen.Task`, and the explicit callback are gone. The function calls look almost normal. The main remaining differences between coroutines and regular functions are the `yield` statement, and using `raise gen.Return` to return a value from the subroutine.